# Find all possible values of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{2i}{z^2+1} \, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $\gamma$ be a closed and continuously differentiable path in the upper half plane
not passing through $i$. Describe the set of all possible values  of: $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \dfrac{2i}{z^2+1} \, dz$$

My attempt:

$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \dfrac{2i}{z^2+1}=\int_\gamma \dfrac{2i}{z^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\bigg(\int_\gamma\dfrac{1}{z-i}-\int_\gamma\dfrac{1}{z+i}\bigg)$$

since $\gamma$ contains points having $y>0$ so second integral is zero so what will be the possible values of the integral. Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen the [Cauchy Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)? This is a straightforward application. As you've observed, the path $\gamma$ can't wind around the residue at $-i$. Suppose the path winds $n$ times counterclockwise around $i$. By the residue theorem,
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-i}=n.
$$
Taking $\gamma(t)=i+ae^{2\pi int}$ for any $a<1$ shows that $n$ is an arbitrary integer. Thus the set of possible values is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: why take a<1 @prekidney

Comment: Otherwise the path $\gamma$ does not reside in the upper half plane, as you stipulated.