# Find all possible values of $\int_{\gamma} \frac {dz} {1+z^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Find all possible values of $$\int_{\gamma} \frac {dz} {1+z^2}$$ where $\gamma$ is any closed contour not passing through $\pm i$.

Assuming that $\gamma$ is homologous to zero then if both $\pm i$ lying outside $\gamma$ then the integral value is zero. If $i \in I(\gamma)$ but $-i \notin I(\gamma)$ then by Residue theorem it follows that the integral value is $\pi n(\gamma;i)$ and if  $i \notin I(\gamma)$ but $-i \in I(\gamma)$ then by Residue theorem it follows that the integral value is $-\pi n(\gamma;-i)$ and when both of $\pm i \in I(\gamma)$ then by applying the same theorem it follows that the integral value is $\pi [n(\gamma;i)-n(\gamma;-i)]$; where $I(\gamma)$ denotes the interior of $\gamma$ and $n(\gamma;a)$ denotes the winding number of $\gamma$ around $a$.

Is it correct at all? Please check it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all possible values of $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \dfrac{2i}{z^2+1} \, dz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101021/find-all-possible-values-of-dfrac12-pi-i-int-gamma-dfrac2iz21-d)

Comment: See Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101021/find-all-possible-values-of-dfrac12-pi-i-int-gamma-dfrac2iz21-d?rq=1

Comment: I have edited my question. Actually I have forgotten to multiply the integral value with $2\pi i$. I apologize for that. Is it now ok?

Comment: It looks ok to me